# Dynamically add attribute and set value based on parent dynamic attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, dynamically-generated

Hello everybody I'm trying to convert this xml:

```
<element>
    <element>
      <element>

      </element>
    </element>
    <element>

    </element>
</element>
```

To this:

```
<element test="">
    <element test="f">
      <element test="ff">

      </element>
    </element>
    <element test="f">

    </element>
</element>
```

So concat whatever parent/@test has with "f" and so on.

I currently have this xml:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()" mode="copying">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="copying"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[not(self::newline or self::tab or self::space)]" mode="copying">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" mode="copying"/>

      <xsl:attribute name="test">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="parent::*">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(../@test,'    ')"/>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="''"/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" mode="copying"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

But it just ignores the parent attribute's value. Can somebody please help me?

Comment: Your input elements don't have any `test` attributes and your whole stylesheet (like all stylesheets) works on the input tree, not on dynamically created result nodes. So you need to pass on any value as a parameter and concatenate that parameter value and insert it as an attribute.

Comment: It is intended that the input elements don't have the 'test' attribute. How would I go about on doing what you said? could you show me an example?

Comment: Can you use an XSLT 2.0 processor? With tunnel attributes it is easier.

Comment: No I'm forced to use xslt 1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With XSLT 2.0 you can use

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[not(self::newline or self::tab or self::space)]">
        <xsl:param name="test" tunnel="yes" select="''"/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="test" select="$test"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()">
                <xsl:with-param name="test" tunnel="yes" select="concat($test, 'f')"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

with XSLT 1.0 you need to make sure the identity transformation template (the first template) and all other templates you might have pass on the parameter as well:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:param name="test"/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()">
                <xsl:with-param name="test" select="concat($test, 'f')"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[not(self::newline or self::tab or self::space)]">
        <xsl:param name="test" select="''"/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="test">
                <xsl:value-of select="$test"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()">
                <xsl:with-param name="test" select="concat($test, 'f')"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: For some reason I thought templates that use match cannot use params. I did not need the 'tunnel' attribute it worked without it. Thanks a lot!